# Using .pyc files instead .py with roslaunch

Tags: python, rospy, ros-noetic, binaries

I am working on a docker and using ROS 1 noetic as of now.

For certain reasons I do not want to distribute .py files as end user do not need to understand what is inside there. So I am using .pyc files generated using python module [compileall](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/compileall.html).

When I try to launch .pyc file on the local machine with Ubuntu (not on the docker) it works perfectly fine. But when I put it inside the docker, it throws the following error while launching.

```bash
If it is a script, you may be missing a '#!' declaration at the top.
```

I have already provided execution permition to the file.
Any idea what am I missing here?

**[Update]**

**Progress**.. **A different error**..
After updating CMakeLists.txt by adding following,

```
catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS 
  scripts/control_lib.pyc
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

Now I am getting `RuntimeError: Bad magic number in .pyc file`

But it doesn't make sense as file is compilled on the docker.

**[Try it yourself]**

Here is a simple example to reproduce the error.
https://github.com/aarsht7/pyc_test

It contains simple talker node with python.

When used .py file in the [roslaunch](https://github.com/aarsht7/pyc_test/blob/364e9ad3ebc8658a621e967e81c91612eed3c3ba/src/talker/launch/talker.launch#L13), it behaves as it should be. While usin .pyc file in [roslaunch](https://github.com/aarsht7/pyc_test/blob/364e9ad3ebc8658a621e967e81c91612eed3c3ba/src/talker/launch/talker.launch#L8), it throws `RuntimeError: Bad magic number in .pyc file`

Comment: I checked python version on both, they are similar. I tried to complie the file on the docker and use that file instead of cloning pyc generated on local machine, did not worked. same error in both the cases

Comment: This seems to be a generic python problem and only related to robotics by where you want to use it.

Comment: I'll convert this to an answer if this gets reopened, this worked (outside of docker at least, haven't tested inside it) using python 3.11: `python -m compileall \`rospack find talker\``,   `<node pkg="talker" type="talker.sh" name="talker_pyc" output="screen"/>`
then in scripts/talker.sh wrapper script:  `#!/bin/bash` `python \`rospack find talker\`/scripts/__pycache__/talker.cpython-311.pyc`

Comment: Thing is pyc files worked on the local machine as well.  it's just docker that is struggling with pyc. I will try your suggestion in docker for confirmation. 

But for now, I have decided to try pyinstaller to generate distributable bundle file. Just that it take up more storage than the pyc file as it packs all the dependancy togather so I am not sure if I will continue using pyinstaller

Comment: I tried docker and see the same `RLException: Unable to launch If it is a script,..` (I think any time you saw `Bad magic` that's from running a pyc from a different python version, probably the outside one)- but the wrapper worked.  So the issue is something different with any combination of ros or python versions or the docker environment vs. outside docker.

Comment: When you see `RLException: Unable to launch If it is a script,..` It is because you forgot to give excecution permission ig. I faced the same error but after `chmod +x filename.*` it gave the `Bad magic` error

Comment: I tried the solution mentioned above by Lucas and it worked for me. TO BE MENTIONED HERE, I tried everything on the docker and it has only one version of python3 installed that delivered with installation of the ros from the official ros-docker image. So at the end it seem to be a problem of the roslaunch and the python version it might be using on backend and not the python3. I felt it was bit rude the closing of the question without listining or understanding the issue but anyway.